# Process builder is not working as expected

Tags: apex, soql, community, process-builder, businessprocess

I got a requirement like I have case record type called customer.Whenever any case is created with specific set of fields.i need to update specific field in opportunity.

So,In that record type Look up relationship is there with opportunity.So, i write a process in process builder it is not updating anything.Even i met the criteria.

for reference:
[image: Criteria]

[image: Immediate action]

In immediate field action.When i select related records.It doesn't shows 
opportunityId.It showing like
opportunity name->AccountId->opportunities

Even i put reference or formula in field update anything is not working.

Please suggest where is missed it.

After your suggestion.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can actually go up and then back down, or down and then back up... no sources to back it up but it doesn't seem like it even *should* work.

Comment: I created lookup relationship normally.But why i am not getting opportunity-id in related action.@Adrian Larson

Comment: so you only want to update the Case's parent Opportunity? Not all Opportunities on the Case's Account?

Comment: Yes you are right.@cropredy

Comment: Any solution for this @cropredy

Answer (score 3):

Pavan

Assuming that the relationship is Opportunity (parent) -> Case (child), then the Process Builder flow to update a field on the Oppo can be as simple as:

[image]

Note that the Immediate Actions is "Update Record", and "Record" to update is `[Case].Opportunity`. This is the parent Opportunity to the triggering Case object.

The Field update is an example only - I appended the `Case.Subject` to the `Opportunity.Name` field

If the Case has no Opportunity, nothing will happen

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the Case's parent Opportunity then you need to change the record selection.  Instead of [Case].Opportunity Name.Account Id.Opportunities it should read [Case].Opportunity__c.

When you select the record do not choose the `Opportunity >` option, instead scroll down more where you should see simply `Opportunity` in the drop down list.

Comment: But i want to filter only opportunities related to that case.So i filtered lookup with opportunity Opportunity Name: Account Name IDEQUALSCase: Account Name ID @Doug B

Comment: I tried remove lookup filter.But i unable to update.i named opportunity name for my lookup and updated my question can you look on that @Doug B